# UWP app can't be updated after new certificate

Tags: uwp, certificate, ssl-certificate

Our UWP app recently got a updated certificate (pfx). New users are able to install it, but users with previous versions cannot update.

When they try to update they get the message:

> Ask the developer for a new app package. This package may conflict
>   with a package that is already installed or it may depend on things
>   not installed here (package dependencies) or be made for a different
>   architecture (0x80073CF3)

A workaround to this is to uninstall it and reinstall it, but group policy for our customer prevents this. Is there a way of updating without uninstalling?

The package family name (subject) is different in the new licence.

When installing via Powershell:

> Windows cannot install package
>   *******_12.1.0.0_neutral_~_83zx72fh7sqme because a different package *******_13.2.1.0_x86__e91qp94tx8r3y with the same name is already installed. Remove package *******_13.2.1.0_x86__e91qp94tx8r3y
>   before installing.

**UPDATE** We got a certificate from a different provider with EXACTLY the same subject and are able to update the app rather than reinstall it.

Comment: Currently, there are no other ways to update the app when the certificate is changed if you don't uninstall and re-install the app.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT If I could get our IT department to make the updated certificate have the same publisher as the original, could an update work? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT If a certificate is simply updated, should it be possible to update the app rather than reinstall?

Comment: Yes if the Subject is exactly the same it should work.