# Windows considers it a different app after changing signing method

Tags: windows, installation, uwp

We've been working on a Windows UWP application for a couple of years. In the past, we've been distributing it through Microsoft Store and also giving out some copies to testers with a self-signed certificate.

Recently we decided to start distributing builds directly, so we obtained a trusted certificate from a certificate authority. The problem is that when someone tries to install the new build on a computer, Windows complains that it "cannot install package because a different package with the same name is already installed", and requires that the old app be uninstalled before the new one can be used.

What causes this? Is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the new certificate is exactly the same as the original one for all the subjects.

A similar issue here: [UWP app can't be updated after new certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882557/uwp-app-cant-be-updated-after-new-certificate).